# Abstract ForeignKey without using GenericForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

To create a generic versioning for my models I have created a model `Version`:

```
class Version(models.Model):
    version_number = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

and an abstract models `VersionedModel`

```
class VersionedModel(models.Model):
    ...
    versions = models.ManyToManyField(Version, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s")

class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

everything works but I would like to have the database check that each version is assigned to one and only one object.

What I can think of is to modify the field `versions` and use `through` to create and intermediate table where I could then use a unique index on version_id, but I am just back to the initial problem of creating a `ForeingKey` field to an abstract model.

I don't like using `GenericForeignKey` as they create all sort of headaches when working with graphene. I wondered if there is a way to model this in a different way, or to use some constraint I am not aware of, so that the database can provide completeness and uniqueness on its own.

Comment: Then you do not need a `ManyToManyField`, but a `OneToOneField`.

Comment: Technically is a one to many: an object can have multiple versions, each version can only belong to one object. But one to many are not supported and foreign keys to abstract classes are not supported either.

Comment: so if I understand it correctly, each `Version` should refer to only *one* `VersionedModel` object. Is that an object over all the subclasses of you `VersionedModel`, or at most one *per* subclass of the `VersionedModel`?

Comment: only one over all the subclasses

Comment: I could use normal inheritance instead of an abstract model, but if that is the only option I am tempted to ignore the problem.